# No sound after clean install

Tags: drivers, 12.10, alsa, soundcard

Did a clean install of Ubuntu 12.10 and everything working great except for the sound.

Ubuntu doesn't even seem to be recognizing the fact my HP dv6000 has the capability of making sound!

I have the `dummy output` problem, and when I try to open `alsamixer` using terminal I get the message that `no such file or directory exists.` I can't get it to recognize any soundcards or audio devices at all.

I've been working on the problem for a couple days now and have even taken the laptop apart to ensure that all cables are properly attached...

When I go into the `PhoenixBIOS` there are no sound options that I can find. The laptop does make a loud beep if I press buttons in the BIOS, but once it boots to the hard drive, the thing is mute.  HELP!

Comment: Did you install ubuntu-restricted-extras ????

Comment: Not that I know of.  How do I do that?

Comment: Okay, I think I did that.  I went to the terminal and loaded did a sudo command that I found online, and then the computer spent a couple of minutes installing soome things from the ubuntu-restricted-extras.  I waited for the installation to run its course and the rebooted.  Nothing has seemed to change though...

Comment: Possible duplicate? - see my answer here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/264272/no-sound-output-msi-k8n-neo4-ck804-ac97/274381#274381

Answer (score 3):

please, when you find a solution for your problem post the steps to solve it.

in order to install ubuntu-restricted-extras open terminal and execute
'

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

'

Comment: Okay, I am sure that I did that When I execute those commands it tells me that I already have the newest version.  I will definitely post a solution once I find it.  Is it possible that I need to install a driver?  I can't find a driver online that matches both my hp dv6700 and ubuntu 12.10...