# No sound output (MSI K8N NEO4/CK804 AC'97)

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a K8N NEO4 motherboard with a built in AC'97 sound card. It has a digital spdif output I wish to utilize.

My reciever is a Denon AVR 1709 which supports afaik DTS/AC3 in 44100 & 48000 hz. (It works with ATV2+xbmc+spdif/passthrough).

uname -a:

> Linux monster 3.5.0-25-generic #39~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 26 00:07:14 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsmod|grep snd:

> snd_intel8x0           38578  3
>
> snd_ac97_codec        134870  1 snd_intel8x0
>
> ac97_bus               12767  1 snd_ac97_codec
>
> snd_pcm                97523  3 snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec
>
> snd_seq_midi           13325  0
>
> snd_rawmidi            30750  1 snd_seq_midi
>
> snd_seq_midi_event     14900  1 snd_seq_midi
>
> snd_seq                61931  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
>
> snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
>
> snd_seq_device         14498  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
>
> snd                    83674  12 snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
>
> soundcore              15092  1 snd
>
> snd_page_alloc         18573  2 snd_intel8x0,snd_pcm

aplay -L:

```
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
sysdefault:CARD=CK804
    NVidia CK804, NVidia CK804
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=CK804,DEV=0
    NVidia CK804, NVidia CK804
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=CK804,DEV=0
    NVidia CK804, NVidia CK804
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=CK804,DEV=0
    NVidia CK804, NVidia CK804
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=CK804,DEV=0
    NVidia CK804, NVidia CK804
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=CK804,DEV=0
    NVidia CK804, NVidia CK804
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=CK804,DEV=0
    NVidia CK804, NVidia CK804
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=CK804,DEV=0
    NVidia CK804, NVidia CK804 - IEC958
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=CK804,DEV=0
    NVidia CK804, NVidia CK804
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=CK804,DEV=2
    NVidia CK804, NVidia CK804 - IEC958
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=CK804,DEV=0
    NVidia CK804, NVidia CK804
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=CK804,DEV=2
    NVidia CK804, NVidia CK804 - IEC958
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=CK804,DEV=0
    NVidia CK804, NVidia CK804
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=CK804,DEV=2
    NVidia CK804, NVidia CK804 - IEC958
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=CK804,DEV=0
    NVidia CK804, NVidia CK804
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=CK804,DEV=2
    NVidia CK804, NVidia CK804 - IEC958
    Hardware device with all software conversions
a52:CARD=CK804
    NVidia CK804
```

Current settings (changes vs stock):

/etc/pulse/daemon.conf

> default-sample-channels = 6
>
> enable-lfe-remixing = yes

/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf:

> options snd-hda-intel model=auto

This is my alsamixer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIc8m.png

This is my pacmd / list-sinks output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAd6D.png

```
 >>> list-sinks
 1 sink(s) available.
   * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_04.0.iec958-ac3-surround-51>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9958
    volume: 0: 100% 1: 100% 2: 100% 3: 100% 4: 100% 5: 100%
            0: 0.00 dB 1: 0.00 dB 2: 0.00 dB 3: 0.00 dB 4: 0.00 dB 5: 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 100%
                 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 6ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe
                 Surround 5.1
    used by: 0
    linked by: 1
    fixed latency: 95.99 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_04.0>
    module: 4
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = ""
        alsa.id = ""
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = ""
        alsa.device = "0"
        device.string = "a52:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "50796"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "16932"
        device.access_mode = "mmap"
        device.profile.name = "iec958-ac3-surround-51"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Surround 5.1 (IEC958/AC3)"
        device.description = " Digital Surround 5.1 (IEC958/AC3)"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "NVidia CK804"
        alsa.long_card_name = "NVidia CK804 with ALC850 at irq 22"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_intel8x0"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:04.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.name = "CK804 AC'97 Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
```

I have also fiddled around a lot in Unity, pavucontrol, the standard audio settings etc. Nothing seems to help.

At some points in my travels I have managed to get white noise out in the front speakers. I have also once managed to get normal stereo sound out once.

"speaker-test -c6 " sometimes (sometimes as with some certain settings) produces white noise in two channels (never all 6).

I dont have sound out from my normal 3.5mm stereo plugs either, neither front or back.

I have tried reinstalling alsa/pulseaudio many times, also reverting back to complete stock settings with no measurable successes.

Sorry about the images, I cant copy-paste the text properly formatted for some reason.

Is it possible something defaults to use the analog spdif instead of the optical?
Is there some idiot-safe way to get this working? Right now I would be happy to even have a reliable way to produce analog (3.5mm) stereo output just to make sure there isnt something fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and my onboard sound...

1. Run the following command in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa- base.conf
   ```
2. And add the following line at the end

   ```
   options snd-hda-intel model=3stack
   ```